# How to build a basis for a vector space E(n+1) from a set of points given in E(n) (a vector space of rank n).

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras

I'm interested in how (and if) one can build a new dimension from a set of given dimensions.
Specifically, if we are given a vector space E(n) of rank n, and a sample S of elements of E(n) (let us say, S arbitrarily big):

Can we build a vector basis for some E(n+1) of rank n+1?

I'm also interested in keywords or themes that study this kind of questions in maths (if any).

I've been looking up for Lie brackets, unstable operations in vector fields, and words such as involutivity and extension algebras.

Thank you.

Addendum, following the answers and the questions below: I am working on a data structure where points are taken from $\left\{ 0,1\right\}^{m}$ where m can potentially go to $\infty$. At a given moment, I only have points taken from $\left\{ 0,1\right\}^{n}$ where n < m.

Then, if I want to add an extra dimension, I have m-n possibility to do so - which may be a lot.  Instead of doing this arbitrarily, I would like to have a kind of principled way
or at least a mathematical understanding of such an operation (i.e. that takes as input N points from E(n) and returns a basis for E(n+1).

Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to go up a dimension, you need new elements. Unless your $E(n)$ already lives somewhere larger, you need to do something rather arbitrary to do this (but obviously, you can always formally add a dimension).

Comment: Of course you can always define an $n+1$ dimensional vector space from $n+1$ points, but this potentially won't have anything to do with the old vector space. If a vector space is $n$-dimensional, this is in a hand-wavy sense equivalent to all algebraic operations compatible with the space on all elements yielding at most $n$-dimensional sets.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that E(n) lives on somewhere (much) larger. My aim is to find an operation (or algorithm) that can build B' of E(n+1) out of points in E(n). Or a mathematical notion or result that prove that it can be done (maybe trivially..)

Comment: Where do you assume $E(n)$ to live? It sounds like you have something specific in mind, in which case you need to provide those details.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. What do you mean 'take as input $N$ points from $E(n)$ and returns a basis for $E(n+1)$? If we know what the subspace $E(n)$ is, then we don't need to be given some set of points from it in order to extend it by one dimension. If $E(1)=\{(0,0,\ldots),(1,0,\ldots)\}$ then it's clear that we can extend to $E(2)$ by adding any vector linearly independent from $E(1)$ and the span of $E(1)$ together with this new vector. There's no canonical way to do this, although the simplest would be to consider the new vector $(0,1,0,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E(n)$ be a given vector space over the field $K$ and define $E(n+1)$ by $E(n+1)=E(n)\oplus K$ where $K$ is seen as a $1$-dimensional vector space over itself and $\oplus$ is the [direct sum of vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_two_vector_spaces). Given that $E(n)$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$, we see that $E(n+1)$ is an $n+1$-dimensional vector space over $K$ from basic linear algebra.

If $B$ is a basis for $E(n)$ then $B'=\{(v,0_K)\mid v\in B\}\cup\{(0_{E(n)},1_K)\}$ is a basis for $E(n+1)$.

Any other $n+1$-dimensional vector space over $K$ with an embedded $E(n)$ is naturally isomorphic to this vector space via an isomorphism which restricts to the identity on the embedded $E(n)$ subspaces.